# Extracting XML auto data via stored procedure in java (MS SQL)

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using the below query to be returned via stored-procedure,

```
SELECT * FROM test FOR XML AUTO
```

This inturn gives me the following result when I run the stored procedure,

OUTPUT in server:

```
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
.........
```

When I tried to execute the procedure via preparecall in java, and I tried returning the result set, this should return one xml string but I am getting this splitted like below,

```
Record1:
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data
Record 2: 1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test column1="data1" column2="data2" />
<test colu
.............. and so on.
```

Below is piece of my code,

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection connection = getConnection();
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{call test_proc()}");
ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();

while(rs.next()){
        c++;
        System.out.println("Record "+c+":"+rs.getString(1));
}
System.out.println("Count : "+c);
```

This is inturn returning count 3 rather than 1, but it is working fine in sql server when i run this as an anonymous procedure.

I also tried `getSQLXML(int column)` method, but no use.

Some one could you please help on this?

Adding one more point : I tried simple query execution (via java code) - `SELECT * FROM test FOR XML AUTO`  and tried getting the resultset, still it provides the same result. :(

Comment: it looks really strange, are you sure your stored procedure returns 1 row?

Comment: Yes For sure, In my server it returns a table with a column name "XML-6457836-.. some number" and it contains only one record which is the whole XML.

Comment: what is the expected output xml ?

Comment: I want the actual output which has been mentioned as "OUTPUT in server:" (i.e. all the xml at once). Also I just can't understand, why the result set is providing 3 records rather than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Add ELEMENTS as well as both the column are in same table.

```
SELECT * FROM test FOR XML AUTO ,ELEMENTS
```

Comment: ELEMENTS is required when you want this to be appended as single formed xml like <test> (the columns as childs) </test>, But I am not sure this will resolve the problem.